# Python - How to read the content of an URL twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am using 'urllib.request.urlopen' to read the content of an HTML page. Afterwards, I want to print the content to my local file and then do a certain operation (e.g. construct a parser on that page e.g. Beautiful Soup).

**The problem**
After reading the content for the first time (and writing it into a file), I can't read the content for the second time in order to do something with it (e.g. construct a parser on it). It is just empty and I can't move the cursor(*seek(0)*) back to the beginning.

```
import urllib.request   


response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com")


file = open( "myTestFile.html", "w")
file.write( response.read()  )    # Tried response.readlines(), but that did not help me
#Tried: response.seek()           but that did not work
print( response.read() )          # Actually, I want something done here... e.g. construct a parser:
                                  # BeautifulSoup(response).
                                  # Anyway this is an empty result 


file.close()
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can not read the response twice.  But you can easily reuse the saved content:

```
content = response.read()
file.write(content)
print(content)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it response.write(content) ?